# Provider: ListView.builder not updating on editing one element

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm using the Provider package to Read, Edit and Delete elements from a list.

My class provider contains all 3 elements, but I'm only having trouble with the Editing bit. Here is the relevant part of the code:

**main.dart**

```
...

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => UserProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => GenreProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

...
```

**genre_provider.dart**

```
class GenreProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> _genres = [];

  Future fetchGenres() async {
    ...
  }

  Future updateGenre(String id, String title) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('genres')
          .doc(id)
          .update({'title': title});
      var updatedGenre = _genres.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
      updatedGenre['title'] = title;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e);
    }
  }

  void removeGenre(String id) async {
  ...

  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get getGenres {
    return _genres;
  }
}
```

**genre_list.dart** (The calling of the function is under 'showEditTitleDialog')

```
class GenreListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/genre-list';

  @override
  _GenreListScreenState createState() => _GenreListScreenState();
}

class _GenreListScreenState extends State<GenreListScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _keyDialogForm = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var initialGenreTitle = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: 'List of all musical Genres'),
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer<GenreProvider>(
          builder: (context, genreProvider, child) {
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> genreList = genreProvider.getGenres;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var genre = genreList[index];

                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(genre['id']),
                  background: kDismissibleContainer,
                  onDismissed: (_) => GenreProvider().removeGenre(genre['id']),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(genre['title']),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _titleController.text = genre['title'];
                            showEditTitleDialog(context, genre);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: genreList.length,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future showEditTitleDialog(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> genre) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
        title: Form(
          key: _keyDialogForm,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                ),
                controller: _titleController,
                maxLength: 20,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _titleController.text = value;
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter a genre, please.';
                  } else if (value.length < 2) {
                    return 'Too short.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_keyDialogForm.currentState.validate()) {
                _keyDialogForm.currentState.save();
                try {
                  await GenreProvider()
                      .updateGenre(genre['id'], _titleController.text);
                } on Exception catch (_) {
                  showSnackBar(
                    text: 'Unknown error updating the genre.',
                    color: Colors.red,
                    context: context,
                  );
                } finally {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              }
            },
            child: Text(
              'Save',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              'Cancel',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, I can fetch the whole list, I can remove it with the Dismissible, but on Editing nothing changes. I see the database changes, but nothing on the UI.

Edit: I wrote a 'print' statement inside the ListView.build builder method, showing that it nevers updates.

I can 'force' the redrawing of the UI with 'setState(() {})', but that's bad code and I want to use the proper methods.

Seems like I'm forgetting something small, but I fail to see it. The function works, I use notifyListeners() after the 'await' section, but it is not updating the UI.

What I am missing on the code?

Comment: did you check that _genres.firstWhere actually returns a map instance? it doesn't seems plausible but if the db updates then it seems there is a problem in the next line, instead of checking inside the ListView.builder, check the consumer to see if it actually updates and maybe the listview is just ignoring it

Comment: Yes, it does. But as a test I removed everything inside the update function, leaving just a print and the notifyListeners(). Still nothing. It is weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after re reading your code I found your error, you're not using the class that is being provided, you're creating it anew

```
await GenreProvider().updateGenre(genre['id'], _titleController.text); //This is not the same instance that you
```

You shouldn't create a new class `GenreProvider()`, use `Provider.of(context)` to get the one your app is using

```
Future showEditTitleDialog(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> genre) {
  final genreProvider = Provider.of<GenreProvider>(context, listen: false);
  //.... your code
  onTap: () {
     //......
     await genreProvider.updateGenre(genre['id'], _titleController.text);
  }
 
}
```

Also in your dismissible

```
onDismissed: (_) => genreProvider.removeGenre(genre['id']),
```

The fact that you're not seeing the same error when using dismiss is that the method actually deletes the object from your DB and then dismiss widget does the animation, but if you debug you'll actually find that the object remains in _genres, is just the UI that hidden it

Comment: You're right.... I don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot!